# How do I bind current column value in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a feature in my web app where a table is "quick-editable", that is, its cells can be edited directly. When the user saves his changes, the client sends to the server the changed rows, with their changed columns (excluding non-changed columns, just to clarify), and their corresponding IDs.

In order to do `UPDATE` queries efficiently, I am using PDO's prepared statement feature. Here is an equivalent statement what I currently came up:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET
   col1 = :arg_col1,
   col2 = :arg_col2,
   col3 = :arg_col3
WHERE
   ID = :arg_ID
```

Then I came up with this problem in which I cannot set a column into its current value. Because only the edited column(s) in a row is/are submitted, I only need to bind the data to their respective column(s). For example, if only `col1` and `col2` are changed, the resulting statement should be

```sql
UPDATE table
SET
   col1 = 'new data',
   col2 = 'an edit',
   col3 = col3   /* Use the current value of the column */
WHERE
   ID = 153454
```

Modifying the statement directly would definitely nullify the performance improvement of using the same prepared statement for updating multiple rows. Sadly, PDO doesn't seem to have an option to bind a column to its current value.

How should I solve this problem?

---

**ADDITIONAL:** I do not wish to send all the columns, for performance reasons.

Comment: store the value in a variable and bind the column to that variable

Comment: Try this "efficient" solution in real first. You'd be surprised.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah. I'm just making the most out of every opportunity. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, an approach you are aiming to, won't actually work. You just can't prepare a statement in one call and then use it in all subsequent calls - you'll have to prepare it every time again.
So, there is no point in creating a generic query. Thus, you can create a custom query for the very data set. And this latter task can be automated: just create your UPDATE statement dynamically.

A solution, based on the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) (scroll to the very bottom):

```
// first, have your update data in array (you can omit this line though)
$update = $_POST;

// next, list all fields a user allowed to
$allowed = array("col1","col2","col3");

// finally, create a SET statement query dynamically
$set = pdoSet($fields,$values, $update);

// voila - your query contains only fields were POSTed:
$sql = "UPDATE users SET $set WHERE id = :id";
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);

// just add an ID and execute
$values["id"] = $_POST['id'];
$stm->execute($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't want the `col3` in the sql, what you need to do is to build the sql dynamically, only add the changed columns to the sql.

Comment: But I want to prepare the statement once and apply it to all the rows. Aren't there any alternatives?